# Why is the __proto__ of Object.prototype, another Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, google-chrome-devtools, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

If we create an array in chrome console,

```
arr=[1,2];
```

and check the prototype chain in chrome devtools using `arr.__proto__.__proto__`, we get the following result.
[image]

As you can see, the `__proto__` object is pointing to null, which I was expecting logically.
But when I tried to access the same level of the prototype chain, i.e the `Object.Prototype`, by using `arr.__proto__`, and then searching through the dropdown menus, I got the following result.
[image]

As you can see in the highlighted line, this time the `__proto__` is pointing to another `Object.Prototype`. On opening this further, I got the same contents as I got in the previous command(check previous pic).

Can someone please tell me how this extra layer of an `Object.prototype` is created in some commands, but not in others?

P.S. I'm just learning prototypal inheritance, and this was my attempt to understand how it is implemented in the JS environment.

Comment: Ugh, that's awful. *"I'm just learning prototypal inheritance"* and *"As you can see, the __proto__ object is pointing to null, which I was expecting logically."* You seem to be doing a good job learning! Because you're exactly right. The prototype of `arr` is `Array.prototype`, and its prototype is `Object.prototype`, and *its* prototype is `null`. So nice one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to an odd behavior in Chrome dev tools. The (now deprecated) `__proto__` property is a getter/accessor property, which means when it is accessed, it runs a portion of code. That portion of code looks something like so:

```js
Object.getPrototypeOf(this); // which returns this[[Prototype]]
```

The `this` in the above example is typically the object that you call `.__proto__` on. For example, if you did `arr.__proto__`, then `this` would be `arr`, so we end up getting the prototype of the `arr` array as expected. In the Chrome dev tools console, things are a little different. Rather than the getter being invoked on an object like `arr`, it is instead invoked manually when you press `(...)`:

[image: Image showing how an ellipsis icon can be pressed for the proto getter property]

So now the question is - what is the value of `this` when performing `Object.getPrototypeOf(this);` inside of the `__proto__` getter when it is invoked manually in the Chrome dev tools rather than invoking it via property access such as `arr.__proto__`? This is up to the Chrome dev tools team to decide, but it seems like the way that it behaves is that it sets the `this` to the originally logged object<sup>1</sup>. In your second example, that object is `arr.__proto__`. As a result, the getter ends up showing the prototype of `arr.__proto__` again, rather than `null`.

The below code snippet (see Chrome console output), is a simple example of this behavior in action:

```js
const obj = Object.create({
  get nested() {
    console.log("obj === this:", this === obj); // true
    console.log("obj[[Prototype]] === this:", this === Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)); // false
    return this;
  }
}, {
  foo: {
    value: 'bar',
    enumerable: true
  }
});

// View chrome console for output
console.log(obj);
```

In the above example, a new object is created with the property `{foo: "bar"}` which has a prototype set to an object with a getter called `nested() {}`. This getter returns and logs the value of `this`. When the above code is run in Chrome, and the getter is invoked by clicking `(...)` on `obj[[Prototype]]` (ie: `obj.__proto__`) `nested` property, you get the following output:

[image: image to show that the nested getter logs the original object]

In the above, the two red boxes represent the *same* object, showing that `this` inside of the getter doesn't refer to the prototype object (ie: `{nested: (...)}`) when it is invoked using `(...)`, but rather it refers to the originally logged object. Unlike this, when you use `arr.__proto__.__proto__`, the object logged is `Object.prototype`, so when you invoked the `__proto__` getter, the `this` refers to the object `Object.prototype`, which returns `null` when its prototype is accessed.

To properly walk the prototype chain, you can use nested calls to `Object.getPrototypeOf()`:

```js
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(arr))); // null
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is just an assumption based on some observations, but might not be correct - I'm not entirely sure how chrome decides what to set the `this` to, but the important thing to note is that it isn't always the immediate object that the getter property appears in.

Comment: This smells a **lot** like a bug in Chrome's devtools. Excellent analysis! Just Yet Another reason not to use `__proto__`. :-)

Comment: *"To properly walk the prototype chain..."* And to do it in devtools, use the [[Prototype]] link, not the `__proto__` link.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder :), it seems like a bug to me too. Good point about using `[[Protoype]]` in the console, that's probably the easiest way to traverse it.

Comment: Great Answer! Now that I think about it, that feature of Chrome does make sense. Since the `__proto__` property resides on the Object.prototype, whenever we call it from the command line, it should act on whoever called it, instead of its immediate child. So manually clicking the `__proto__` button nested deep inside the tree, would be exactly the same as it being called by whatever object is on the command line, i.e `arr.__proto__`. That would also explain why this phenomenon cascades until it is 
called inside the section `__proto__:Object`. Each nested __proto__ must be like its own call.